# Convolution theorem - Sum of random variable and constant

Tags: probability, convolution

Problem:

Random variables X, Y are independent. X has normal distribution with parameters (a= 1, b^2 = 4). Y has also normal distribution, but Y is equal to (-X). Find all constants c and k > 0,in order to find X + Y + c and k*X so they would have same distribution.

I found out, it has to be done throught convolution theorem.
So first I will sum two random variables and then compute constant c. But I don't really know how to compute the constant. My idea is to use definite integral of f(z) + c = 1 (f(z) is X+Y). Is it correct?

Comment: Sorry, but how can $X,Y$ be independent if $Y=-X$? Do you mean that it has the same distribution as $-X$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see solution in the image. You don't need to perform convolution as The sum of Gaussian RV's is also Gaussian.

[image: solution]

Comment: Don't sweat it. Notice that I equated only the first two moments. Is it enough to say that the whole distribution is identical? Think about it....

Comment: Okay, I will think about it.

Comment: Also: important: X,Y are independent. So X does not equal -Y. You  probably meant that they have opposite means. Check the question again.

Comment: Please, why these two moments equals?

Comment: Gaussian distribution is completely defined by its first two moments.